# Passing over variables from a file to another using jQuery/AJAX shows empty result

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to fetch the list of transactions through jQuery/AJAX so it will update on any page I have that list on, when I update the content of this file I want to use. But I don't want to have the SQL queries in the file that I get through jQuery/AJAX since I use different queries for different pages on my website.

- The file **transactions.php** contains all the SQL queries that I need. In that file, I also have this line: `<div id="transactions"></div>`.
- The file **fetch-transactions.php** contains this list I want to show on the page. In it I have 2 globals (you know, `global $thevariable`) for 2 required variables (`$count_transactions` (to count the transactions) and `$get_transactions` (to loop the transactions into the list)) that can be found in transactions.php.
- The **javascripts.js** contains all the needed JavaScript codes I have for my website, including this line: `$.get(folder_name + 'ajax/fetch-transactions.php', function(s) { $('div#transactions').html(s); });`

As you maybe already have figure out, **s** contains the content of **fetch-transactions.php**.

The thing is that none of the variables I have set globally in **fetch-transactions.php** have any data in them. The are empty! Why is that? Is it because they are not globally set? I don't want to use `define` as a variable. I don't think that is even possible for fetching data from the database :P

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to read PHP variables in JavaScript. JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server side. The only way you can read the PHP variables into JavaScript is by outputting them within your fetch-transations.php file in some kind of format JavaScript can read.

There's a pretty decent [Stack Overflow resource for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) which you should read.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't think about the difference between PHP and JavaScript. I was too eager to make it work. I'll accept it when I can :)

Comment: No problem, it would be quite dangerous to let the JavaScript have access to the PHP directly so the separation is quite helpful in this case.